# Video hosting platform with tags

Tags: video, youtube

I need a video hosting online service like Youtube or Vimeo who lets me organize in a useful way videos I upload (which need to stay private) with tags/labels and filter them with a search function. Is there something like this on the net? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need a video hosting online service like Youtube or Vimeo who lets me organize in a useful way videos I upload (which need to stay private) with tags/labels and filter them with a search function. Is there something like this on the net?

YouTube lets you do it for free.

- Create a new Channel.
- Upload videos as "Private".
- Create a new Playlist as "Private".
- Tag your videos.
- Use the  "Auto-add" with Tags to place the videos automatically into one or more Playlists.

[image: YouTube ScreenShot]